# Distribution of distance between positions

Tags: distributions, distance

I have N = 3 billion ordered positions, as in a genome that has 3 billion base pairs.

I have R = 3 million, as in 3 million SNPs (Single Nucleotide Polymorphisms) that are (close to) randomly distributed over those 3 billion ordered positions (on the genome).

So on average, each SNP is 1000 base pairs away from SNP that follows it. This distance to the next SNP is what I want to measure.

e.g. If we order the 3 million SNPs by position on the 3 billion base pairs, we may find as an example:

```
R(1) = 482
R(2) = 1,563
R(3) = 1,721
…
R(2,999,999) = 2,999,998,023
R(3,000,000) = 2,999,998,846
```

To get the distance between them, I simply take differences:

```
DR(1) = 1,081
DR(2) = 158
…
DR(2,999,999) = 823
```

I need to be able to determine P(DR[N,R] > x), e.g. to give the percentage of adjacent SNPs that would be further than x = 10,000 base pairs apart when N = 3,000,000,000 and R = 3,000,000.

So what I want to know is if there is a closed form for the probability distribution function of DR as a function of N and R. Is the mean exactly N/R?  And what is the variance?